# Сниффер bluetooth трафика iOS

Tags: ios, парсер, macos, bluetooth, сниффер

Можно ли как-то снифить *bluetooth* трафик на *iPhone*? Нужно запарсить информацию с гироскутера для того, чтобы написать приложение(приложение идет + для часов версия), но никак не могу придумать, как можно пропустить этот трафик через компьютер(*MacOS* или *Windows*), чтобы посмотреть как там идет информация. Или может у кого-то есть примерные запросы для общения таких устройств?

Comment: Возможная копия https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5863088/bluetooth-sniffer-preferably-mac-osx

Answer (score 1):

В принципе это можно сделать с помощью устройства [Ubertooth One](http://hakshop.myshopify.com/products/ubertooth-one). Можно даже использовать его совместно с Android телефоном - просто находка для шпионов-хулиганов=) [Код приложения](https://github.com/mobilesec/android-ubertooth-btle-sniffing). [Статья](http://ubertooth.sourceforge.net/usage/start/) с чего начать.

Можно попытать счастья с [nRF Sniffer](https://www.nordicsemi.com/eng/Products/Bluetooth-low-energy/nRF-Sniffer) от Nordic Semiconductor. Этот снифер использует отладочную плату Nordic со специальной прошивкой, запрограммированной в устройстве. NRF51822 захватывает пакеты BLE, добавляет время, RSSI и другие метаданные и пересылает их в Wireshark.

[TI SmartRF Protocol Packet Sniffer](http://www.ti.com/tool/packet-sniffer). Представляет собой интерфейс, который захватывает пакеты, как и NRF51822. Программа поддерживает и другие протоколы, помимо BL/BLE. В настоящее время доступны только CC2540 USB Dongles или CC2540EM + SMartRF05EB. То есть чипы, которые являются логическим продолжением линейки чипов, используемых в Ubertooth One.

Либо использовать **SDR**([HackRF](https://greatscottgadgets.com/hackrf/), [BladeRF](http://www.nuand.com/) или [USRP N210](https://www.ettus.com/product/category/USRP-Networked-Series)), который поддерживает *ISM* (2.4 - 2.485 ГГц). Это позволит вам захватывать любые радиосигналы в диапазоне *Bluetooth* и особенно **SDR** полезен, если вы хотите определить интерферирующие сигналы, так как сможете посмотреть на общую картину окружающего радиочастотного спектра. Вообще с **SDR** можно сделать очень много интересного - главное уметь его готовить=) И это самый дорогой класс из всего вышеописанного.

Описал только про железную часть, потому как имел с ней дело. Насчет наличия каких-то программных продуктов, использующих обычные *Bluetooth* донглы, я не в курсе.

Резюме. Как по мне, все же проще залезть в программы и подсмотреть реализацию протокола общения, чем ловить все это в эфире.